# Stop audio in a webpage without interacting with DOM

Tags: javascript, webview

I want to stop audio in a webpage but don't have access to the DOM elements. Is there any way I can stop the audio via javascript?

Comment: You can't, the audio lives in the DOM. Just curious, how can you use JS, if you can't access the DOM?

Comment: I can evaluate JS code through my app to control the web view but the framework doesn't have access to the DOM

Comment: Is there some way I can get access to the Video object? @Teemu